# Why pointer is used for socket address in socket programming?

Tags: c, sockets

I have read many pages about socket programming and it's always says something like "Here we use the pointer to the address" and no explanation is given about why pointer is used for socket address.

```
int accept(int sockfd, struct sockaddr *addr, socklen_t *addrlen);
```

Could someone please tell me why pointer is used for socket address?

Comment: Because you want the operating system to populate the `struct sockaddr` for you, so you pass a pointer to it.

Comment: I suggest picking up a copy of Unix Network Programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`man 2 accept`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/accept.2.html) explicitly states the purpose of the `addr` and `addrlen` arguments within its first few paragraphs:

> The argument *addr* is a pointer to a *sockaddr* structure. This structure is filled in with the address of the peer socket, as known to the communications layer. The exact format of the address returned *addr* is determined by the socket's address family (see [socket(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/socket.2.html) and the respective protocol man pages). When *addr* is NULL, nothing is filled in; in this case, *addrlen* is not used, and should also be NULL.

> The *addrlen* argument is a value-result argument: the caller must initialize it to contain the size (in bytes) of the structure pointed to by *addr*; on return it will contain the actual size of the peer address.

In summary, these are pointers to objects you want the system call to fill with information about the newly formed connection.

Comment: I still don't understand perfect clear but made one step forward.
Thank you guys for your help.

Comment: @Jassy whenever a C function outputs data it has to be the return value or a pointer